# How to express this repeated measures model with dummy variables?

Tags: r, regression, repeated-measures, categorical-encoding

I would like to fit a model to predict an outcome at a given time (t=1 in the attached plot) using covariates X.

As I have many missings at that time I've thought  of also using past information of X. I have designed this model to avoid multicollinearity:

*Y ~ (1-t)·X + t·X + t*

For each person I measure *Y* once but I can have a measure of X at two different periods.
I will be getting a coefficient for X at t=0 and a different one at t=1.

Can it be considered "repeated measures" and then I need to use random effects such as...?

*Y ~ (1-t)·X + t·X + t + (1|ID)*

Or this is not applicable here because we have just one Y measure?
Is "repeated measures" used for repeatead Y or for repeated X too?

How would you write the model to also accept people with measures both at t=0 and t=1 simultaneously?
Or would you rewrite it in a different way?

I guess it would be better to use some kind of latent variables.
Another alternative it would be to assign different weights depending on the antiquity of the data, but different covariates (for the same patient) may have been measures at different periods, they can be mixed.

[image]